# How to calculate average where ID is same and then remove duplicates of that ID but keep the one which has average in javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have an object like below

```
{id: "1", score:"2"}
{id: "1", score:"2"}
{id: "1", score:"2"}
{id: "3", score:"3"}
{id: "3", score:"2"}
{id: "3", score:"3"}
{id: "9", score:"4"}
{id: "9", score:"4"}
{id: "9", score:"4"}
```

And expecting an output like below

```
{id: "1", score:"2"}
{id: "3", score:"2.6"}
{id: "9", score:"4"}
```

Comment: Are these objects enclosed in an `array`?. I mean it should be and `score` is `string` or a `number`.

Comment: Yes, objects enclosed in an array and score can be number.

Comment: ok then let me edit my answer

Comment: Edited my answer. Is this what you want?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can easily achieve this using [map](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Map) and [reduce](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/Reduce).

**1)**

```js
const arr = [
  { id: "1", score: 2 },
  { id: "1", score: 2 },
  { id: "1", score: 2 },
  { id: "3", score: 3 },
  { id: "3", score: 2 },
  { id: "3", score: 3 },
  { id: "9", score: 4 },
  { id: "9", score: 4 },
  { id: "9", score: 4 },
];

const result = arr
  .reduce((acc, { id, score }) => {
    const obj = acc.find((el) => el.id === id);
    if (!obj) acc.push({ id, score: [score] });
    else {
      obj.score.push(score);
    }
    return acc;
  }, [])
  .map(({ id, score }) => {
    const total = score.reduce((acc, curr) => acc + curr, 0) / score.length;
    return { id, score: total };
  });
  
  console.log(result);
```

**2)**

```js
const arr = [
  { id: "1", score: 2 },
  { id: "1", score: 2 },
  { id: "1", score: 2 },
  { id: "3", score: 3 },
  { id: "3", score: 2 },
  { id: "3", score: 3 },
  { id: "9", score: 4 },
  { id: "9", score: 4 },
  { id: "9", score: 4 },
];

const result = arr
  .reduce((acc, { id, score }) => {
    const obj = acc.find((el) => el.id === id);
    if (!obj) acc.push({ id, score, len: 1 });
    else {
      obj.score += score;
      ++obj.len;
    }
    return acc;
  }, [])
  .map(({ id, score, len }) => ({ id, score: score / len }));

console.log(result);
```

Comment: @Abrar. Is this what you want

Comment: let me check it.